# Extract a string that has a hashtag, pipe, and 6 chars

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am pretty new to RegEx and I am trying to create a RegEx to match a string with the following criteria.

- Length 8
- First character has to be a hashtag (#)
- Next 3 characters are letters or numbers.
- Pipe is added.
- The next 3 characters are letters or numbers.

Examples... #1Z3|4BC, #ER2|TRD, #123|456, #ABC|ZYX

This is what I have so far: `(?<=#)\w+` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})
```

You can test your regex in https://regexr.com/

It doesn't explicitly declare 8 characters but it's implied by the `#`, `{3}`, `\|`, `{3}`.